# nslooup.c can't deal with http / https?

Tags: c, ubuntu, tcp

I'm trying to do my very first steps at udp/tcp c programing, and I've encounter with a problem.
After compiling and running nslookup.c (I'm using linux Ubuntu) I've receive web information, as long I didn't type protocol before the domain.
For example, typing `./nslookup www.yahoo.com` - will work fine.
How ever, typing `./nslookup http://www.yahoo.com` - will lead to an error :`Error in resolving hostname`.

here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct addrinfo* res;
  char* hostname;
  char* hostaddr;
  struct sockaddr_in* saddr;

  if (argc != 2) {
    perror("Usage: hostnamelookup <hostname>\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  hostname = argv[1];

  if (0 != getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, NULL, &res)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in resolving hostname %s\n", hostname);
    exit(1);
  }

  saddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr;
  hostaddr = inet_ntoa(saddr->sin_addr);

  printf("Address for %s is %s\n", hostname, hostaddr);
  exit(0);
}
```

What is the reason for this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`http://www.yahoo.com` isn't a hostname, it is rather a url.  A url
has (or can have) several components, but in this case, it's
just a protocol (the 'http' part, and a hostname, which is the
`www.yahoo.com` part.  So, that part, being an actual hostname
will (or could, there could be other errors) get resolved,
whereas the url, not being a hostname, will fail.  You may need
to write or use a url parser if you need to do this sort of thing
more generally.